# Bei or von: difference and how to use

Tags: english-to-german, preposition, standard-german

Could someone explain what is a difference "Bei den Fachleuten werden gennant" oder "von den Fachleuten werden gennant"? Which one is correct?

original my sentence: Bei den Fachleuten werden ein Sender und ein Empfänger als Terminal genannt.

Answer (score 2):

Still a bit short on context, but I suggest:

> Fachleute bezeichnen die Kombination aus Sender und Empfänger als *Terminal*.

Notes:

- no article for Fachleute
- genannt has the the double-n behind the *a*
- *Von* Fachleuten is better than *bei*, *unter Fachleuten* or *in Fachkreisen* may also be considered

Comment: could you please explain why we dont use any article for Fachleute? Is there any rule about it?

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva In this case, the determinate article can give the sentence a bit of a determinative vibe. "Die Fachleute" can be read as similar to "diese Fachleute", as in "_andere_ Fachleute verwenden eine andere Bezeichnung". Just "Fachleute" without an article is more read as a category title, like "Menschen, die Fachleute sind, bezeichnen...". It's similar in English, "Experts call..." vs. "The experts call...".

Answer (score 2):

The difference is between any kind of quote vs. a proper citation of some sort of publication.

"von Müller wird etw. [X] genannt"  == "Müller has called this [X]" (could be in  paper, in a keynote speech, a tweet or whatever)

"bei Müller wird etw. [X] genannt" == "Müller's publication calls this [X]" (must be a journal article, book or similar)